# Sqoop export error

Tags: mysql, hdfs, sqoop

I use the Sqoop 1.4.4 to export data from hdfs into mysql.
And got the following error:

```
bin/sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/rec --username root --password root --table rec_temp --export-dir hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000//user/hdfs/part-r-00000 input-lines-terminated-by ' '    

14/12/20 17:14:04 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
14/12/20 17:14:04 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/12/20 17:14:05 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `rec_temp` AS t LIMIT 1
14/12/20 17:14:05 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error reading from database: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@76b03b7f is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@76b03b7f is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
```

More information:

```
part-r-00000 data:
1   [105:1.1617604]
.....

mysql> describe rec_temp;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| rec_value | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Can you help me fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar bug in sqoop reported [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1400) .Please verify the correct MySQL connector version and sqoop version that you are using and update the version as required.Hope this will solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: The error disappears after I change the version of MySQL connector. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another mysql driver version as @Sachin said.

It doesnt't worker with  sqoop-1.6.1 + mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.tar, but works fine when I change to mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar

Answer (score 0):

Add --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --direct
For example, this works for me:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://sandbox.hortonworks.com:3306/retail_db --username retail_dba --password hadoop --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --direct --export-dir /user/horton/weather --table weather
```